# What is the best format for sending formatted (rich) text over REST?

Tags: java, rest, pdf, text

In my current project I've got to create the module that converts formatted text (bold, tables and etc) generated in db to PDF in java.

The question is what is the most suitable specification for sending it between different parts of an application. I thought about brand new html5 spec (it has some interesting text formatting features), but it seems that there aren't any java html5->pdf converters yet.

Or maybe there is nothing better than [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) XHTML renderer project?

Comment: Your question got me confused. Do you want to know what is the best output format for a RESTful service? Or you are asking more specific question?

Comment: "what is the most suitable specification for sending it between different parts of an application?"  (1) Before or after it is a PDF?  And if before, what format is it in before you send it?  (2) By different parts of an application do you mean different parts of an application that are connected only via the internet-- or parts of the application on the same machine?

Comment: 1) before pdf. i tried to figure out how is it saved from my pm, but the only thing he says is that he would generate it from db in the most suitable format (e.g. xhtml, restructuredText). the key is to figure out which format is the most suitable.

2) it might be set of web-apps on single java ee server